# Accessing environment variables in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tfs, environment-variables

I want to access a environment variable from the slave machine and use it when I'm checking out SCM.

I use TFS plugin since TFS is my SCM.

I want a variable to be used in a place as shown in the below image.

[image]

Comment: not yet. I had to use absolute path

Comment: I solved it. I have Jenkins installed in Windows server. I needed to add variables in TFS project path. I used ${VARIABLENAME}. It worked. +1 if it works for you. If it works ill add it in answers section of this post.

Comment: @Ravi Post it as a answer please

Comment: I have added the solution into answer section. +1 if ok

Answer (score 1):

I have Jenkins installed in Windows server. I needed to add variables in TFS project path. I used ${VARIABLENAME}. It worked.